# How do I create a generalized method around setters?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, dao, lombok

I want to define a DAO over a DynamoDB that has 20+ fields. In Java, I can use Lombok and do something like this to avoid a bunch of boilerplate code.

```
@Setter
@Getter
@DynamoDBTable("MyTable")
public class MyDAO {
    //FIELD_1, FIELD_2, FIELD_3 defined as static final String elsewhere

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attribute = FIELD_1) 
    private final String field1;

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attribute = FIELD_2)
    private final Long field2;

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attribute = FIELD_3)
    private final int field3;
    ...
}
```

The problem is if I had methods that did something for each field like the following, I would end up duplicating the code over and over again, because the setters in step 2 would be different and the field names in step 3 would be different (i.e. `setField1` for the first and `setField2` for the second).

```
public void addField1(String key, String field1Value) {
    //Wrap some retry logic and error handling around the following
    // 1. get DAO for key
    // 2. set FIELD_1 to field1Value in DAO if not set
    // 3. put DAO in DynamoDB using attribute name FIELD_1
}

public void addField2(String key, Long field2Value) {
    //Wrap some retry logic and error handling around the following
    // 1. get DAO for key
    // 2. set FIELD_2 to field2Value in DAO if not set
    // 3. put DAO in DynamoDB using attribute name FIELD_2
}
```

Ideally, I would like to have something like the `addField` method below, with all the retry logic so I don't have to duplicate everything for every field.

```
private void addField(String fieldName, String key, Object value);

public void addField1(String key, String field1Value) {
    addField(FIELD_1, key, (Object) field1Value);
}
```

I've tried a map between field names and BiConsumers as such

```
Map<String, BiConsumer<MyDAO, Object>> setterMap = 
    new HashMap<String, BiConsumer<MyDAO, Object>>(){{ 
        put(FIELD_1, MyDAO::setField1);
        put(FIELD_2, MyDAO::setField2);
    }};

private void addField(String fieldName, String key, Object value) {
    ...
    // 2. Use setterMap.get(fieldName).accept(value);
    ...
}
```

The problem is I get an error saying that I cannot cast `BiConsumer<MyDAO, String>` to `BiConsumer<MyDAO, Object>`.

Is it the only way to do it - to create a separate map and method for each type? Or is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: What was your idea around the map and the `BiConsumer`? Can you pehraps show how you used them?

Comment: @ernest_k added more details in question.

Comment: Create a `TriConsumer` interface to put into the map including the field `class `, allowing you to cast the `value`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I don't think it's possible to do it using a `Map` **if** you want to preserve type safety. Instead, here's what I would do:

1) I'd create a special class like that:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
final class FieldDefinition<T> {

    private final String name;
    private final BiConsumer<MyDAO, T> setter;
}
```

2) Then, I'd create constants in `MyDAO` (or, even better, in some helper object near `MyDAO`) like that:

```
static final FieldDefinition<String> FIELD_1_DEF = new FieldDefinition<>(FIELD_1, MyDAO::setField1);
```

3) Finally, I'd create the following type-safe `addField` method:

```
private <T> void addField(FieldDefinition<T> fieldDefinition, String key, T value) {
    // ...
    fieldDefinition.getSetter().accept(this, value);
    // ...
}
```

which whould be called like that:

```
myDao.addField(FIELD_1_DEF, key, value);
```

Answer (score 2):

Dynamic selection of methods is really not a good fit for functional interfaces. Parameterizing your code around method selection is better done with reflection, rather than with functional interfaces.

The main reason making it difficult to implement your logic using the `BiConsumer` interface is that you would technically still have to provide static implementations for it, for each field (whether using lambdas, method references, or classes...).

Here's an example reflection-based implementation:

```
private void addField(String fieldName, String key, Object value) {
    MyDAO.class.getDeclaredField(fieldName).set(value, key);
}
```

So I'd just make `setterMap` a map of key to field name mapping, and use it like so:

```
private void addField(String key, Object value) {
    String field = setterMap.get(key);
    MyDAO.class.getDeclaredField(field).set(value, key);
}
```

Comment: Note that using reflection involves certain [performance penalty](https://blog.frankel.ch/performance-cost-of-reflection/) (of course, this might not be a problem in OP's application - we should remember that "premature optimization is the root of all evil").